# ruby/rails ruby/rails How can I get all the tweets from Twitter LIST (of users) using the Twitter API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, twitter, tweetstream

I would like using the twitter API get all the tweets from a twitter list (of users).
I would like to have a JSON response with the all the tweets in the list. Will parse the JSON to look for hashtags and create graphs.
I would like to use ruby/rails doing it. 
I were not able to find in the twitter API a way to search list.
Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Here you can find all the gems https://rubygems.org/
Here is the documentation for the twitter gem http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter
And an example for all tweets https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/examples/AllTweets.md

Comment: the gems are user related not LIST. My list has over 400 people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I end up doing. In the model i added the function:

```
def self.list_latest()
list = URI.parse('https://twitter.com/USERNAME/LISTNAME')
$client.list_timeline(list).each do |tweet|
  unless exists?(tweet_id: tweet.id)
    create!(
      tweet_id: tweet.id,
      content: tweet.text,
      screen_name: tweet.user.screen_name,
    )
  end
 end 
end
```

I get the tweets from my list and add them to my DB if the tweet ID does not exist.
Hope it helps.